# use one reader object to read more than one result sets from sql database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

Can i use the same reader to read results from two result sets?

```
string checktrigger =

 "select name from sys.triggers where name = 'Insertion_in_ITEMS_table' " +
 "select object_name(parent_obj)from sysobjects where id = 

object_id('Insertion_in_ITEMS_table')";

SqlCommand check_cmd = new SqlCommand(checktrigger, _conn);
SqlDataReader check_reader = check_cmd.ExecuteReader();

string triggername = check_reader.GetString(0);
string tablename = check_reader.GetString(1);

if (triggername.Length != 0)
{
  MessageBox.Show(triggername + "CREATED SUCCESSFULLY" + "ON TABLE " +  triggername + tablename);
}
```

this is giving error that index out of bounds
should i use array? to return the result set

Comment: Use `SqlDataReader.NextResult()`

Comment: @Andomar, NextResult() would extract the string from the next result set or the next row in the same result set

Comment: @Andomar, NextResult() returns the next row from the same table or a row from the next table

Comment: @Andomar, how do i use it in this code? please help me with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User [`reader.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) to get the next record and [`reader.NextResult()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) to switch to the next result in the result set.

```
while (check_reader.Read())
{
    // get rows from the first select
}

// switch to next
check_reader.NextResult();

while (check_reader.Read())
{
    // get rows from the second select
}
```